# Questions in Equilibrium

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium

I have two inquiries concerning equilibrium:

1. Does $K_c = 5.0$ indicate that the equilibrium mixture contains both products and reactants at an approximately equal amount? I know that $K_c \approx 1.0$ is said to be so, however I am unsure of if $5.0$ would be considered to be approximately $1.0$ in this case.
2. Is a reaction at equilibrium if the forward reaction does not change? I believe it would as an indication of equilibrium is that both the forward and reverse reactions occur at the same rate.

Comment: Could you please clarify the line *"Is a reaction at equilibrium if the forward reaction does not change"*? What do you mean by a reaction *not changing*?

Comment: I suppose the OP wants confirmation the equilibrium means a dynamic equilibrium, with the equal rate of the opposite reactions. Yes, it is . By "reaction does not change" he probably means the concentrations are constant.

Comment: I mean to say that the forward reaction maintains a constant rate, which can be said as "the forward reaction does not change".

Comment: You won't get quicker or better answers if you spam Chemistry.SE with the same questions. This is not a paid service, there is no staff constantly sitting on-line and answering all the questions, and you cannot demand a fast and accurate response (plus you already got [one answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/113011/41328) in less than an hour, and in addition to that I already voted to reopen your first question). Please visit [Help Center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) to familiarize yourself with the basic principles of this site.

Comment: If you observed the answer that was given and my following comment, you would have realized that this "answer" was not much of an answer but rather a repetition of the question itself. There is no need for me to familiarize myself with this site. I am already one who knows well of the site's guidelines. Also, there is no need to be so quick to aggression. I am not indicating this as a paid service at all. I am unsure of why anyone would interpret my comment in such a way. We are not fighting here. This a platform for learning. Period.

Comment: If were familiar with the rules, you would've not re-posted the same question just because you were dissatisfied with the first answer given and want a quicker response. I feel pity for you if you see this as aggression or fight, I'm just informing that what you've done wasn't correct; also, as I see it, the answer was as decent as the question itself.

Comment: @James It is very unusual the rate of reaction being constant. Do you have a particular equilibrium in mind ?

Comment: @andselisk, as any other human would do you are trying to defend yourself. Remarking "the answer was as decent as the question itself" is not the appropriate response. The question was in fact detailed in every sense of the word. If you were to be an experienced with the StackExchange clear guidlines, insulting is not allowed in the book. I will not go on if you maintain this manner. There is only one clear purpose of my inquiry. Unless you have a meaningful answer to my inquiry which has been thought through, you comments will not help either you or me. It is as simple as that.

Comment: @James You overestimate the quality and clarity of your question. Additionally, reposting the question instead of elaborating it can be considered rather rude to those who responded.

Comment: I do not overestimate the quality of my question. @Poutnik, my question is very straightforward. Any professor would be shocked at you recent reply remarking "It is very unusual the rate of reaction being constant. Do you have a particular equilibrium in mind?". This is a very primitive question. Let's start from the beginning.

Comment: This is not a laboratory result but rather a hypothetical question which can be answered by the understanding of chemistry. Secondly, I have no particular equilibrium in mind. I am quite surprised that someone is unsure of what equilibrium I am referring to. Just to make it clear, I am referring to the equilibrium of reactions in which the rate of the reverse and forward reactions are equal.

Comment: There are no other equilibriums but those with the equal rates of the opposite reactions.

Comment: @James correct me if I'm wrong but I choose to disagree. A specific example of an equilibrium refers to an equilibrium example with reactants and products for example the equilibrium formed by iron thiocyanate ions in solution. Without a specific example it is difficult to tell if an equilibrium constant 5.0 corresponds to roughly similar amounts of reactants and products

Comment: @James You are quite arrogant for somebody who asks questions with very simple answers you should already know.

Comment: @Poutnik, this is the very reason I am surprised by your response. If there is only one equilibrium, which I knew of before however I did not know of your extent of knowledge, why would you ask "Do you have a particular equilibrium?". You have frankly defeated yourself. If this is such an easy question, why can you not think properly answer it. Your responses have led to nothing more than confusion upon yourself. Not in a way of offense but rather a piece of advise, you should definitely revise the basic chemistry concepts before responding to any questions.

Comment: I have asked about particular equilibrium of context of particular reaction. For chemists, it is clear. No chemist would imply I ask about various kinds of equilibrium. BTW, I graduated in Analytical chemistry 30 years ago.

Comment: @James You should revise your question in the first place. Formulation "reaction does not change" is rather sloppy.

Answer (score 1):

A reaction is in equilibrium,
if the [reaction quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_quotient?wprov=sfla1) $Q=K_{\rm c}$,

For reaction $$\ce{A <=> B}$$ $K_{\rm c}=5$ means concentration ratio 1:5. It does not seem to me to be approximately the same concentrations.

The equilibrium constant is the thermodynamical quantity, determining the position of equilibrium. It's value does not say if the reaction is in equilibrium.

About the same concentrations, it means rather the same **product** of concentrations of reagents and products.

If there is a reaction $$\ce{A + B <=> C + D}$$ with $K_{\rm c}=1$ and if concentrations are $$c_{\rm A}=1000c_{\rm B}=100c_{\rm C}=10c_{\rm D}$$
we can hardly speak about equal concentrations at equilibrium. as $$K_c=1=\frac{10\cdot 100}{1000\cdot 1}$$

Additionally, if a reaction is not symmetric in counts of reagents of both sides, equilibrium concentration ratios change with concentrations.

If there is a reaction $$\ce{A <=> 2 B}$$
The same concentrations during equilibrium with $K_{\rm c}=1$ occur only for $c_{\rm A}=1$.
If we consider concentrations of $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$, the following concentrations are in equilibrium:

- A     B
- 0.0001 0.01
- 0.01 0.1
- 1 1
- 100 10
- 10000 100

---

Yes, you think right, at equilibrium, the rates of the forward and reverse reactions are equal.

If 
$$\begin{align}
rate_{\rm forward}&=const\\
rate_{\rm backward}&=f([products])\\
\end{align}$$
("Forward reaction does not change"=has a constant rate, as was explained)

..then as reaction is progressing, the backward reaction rate increases, until it matches the forward rate and reaction is at equilibrium ( regardless of the $K_{\rm c}$ value.)

Comment: If you are familiar with the concept of the equilibrium constant, which I expect you are, you would know that if Kc, which is the denotation for the equilibrium constant, is approximately 1.0, the reaction is said to be at equilibrium. The issue arises to what is meant by "approximately". This is in fact what my question is asking.

Comment: @James The Kc value and reaction being at equilibrium are 2 independent things. Kc value is matter of reaction thermodynamics, describing the position of the equilibrium state with minimal value of Gibbs energy. Being at equilibrium is matter of reaction kinetics. The Kc value does not say if the reaction already reached equilibrium or not.

Comment: @James A reaction can be in equilibrium for any value of Kc, e.g $10^{52}$